# Don't count votes on error

Tags: bug, voting

Sometimes because of a bad request there is an error when you press the vote buttons, so the vote isn't registered by the server, but the frontend still displays as a successful vote and adds to the total vote count. You can confirm this by refreshing the page and realize that your vote has disappeared. Also, because of this behavior you can't retry to vote on the same page until you reload it.

Could we change this behavior so on an error we still get the error message, but the vote isn't added in the GUI, so we can retry to cast a vote?

[image: Error demonstration]

To test this behavior, just switch to offline mode, or unplug your Internet cable.

Comment: You can retry: click on the upvote button to cancel, and click again to retry.

Comment: Actually I've often noticed the opposite: I vote, it says "An error has occurred" and resets the vote, but after I refresh the vote is there.

Comment: Yeah, without knowing what the error is, the page can't know if the vote has registered or not. Both options will be wrong *some* of the time...

Comment: @Shog9 I agree. But if the vote happened and it shows that it isn't, then one can cast the vote again, and nothing happens (because of server side validation). Everyone happy. However when the vote doesn't happened and it shows that it does, then I have to reload the page or start to think whether the vote did actually happened and the popup is incorrect, or I have to remove the vote and cast it again.